# Can't edit checkout billing information

Tags: checkout, template, frontend, template-hints

I've got a client running a custom theme. I'm trying to edit the checkout field titles / descriptions:

`app/design/frontend/theme/default/template/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml`

The changes I make here are not reflecting on the frontend, even with all caches flushed & disabled. I've even gone as far as disabling the file, (`billing.phtml.disabled`) and directly modifying the base theme to test:

`app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml`

> Please note that modifying the core file was purely for testing purposes & not recommended under any other circumstances

None of these changes are being reflected on the frontend. I feel like I must be missing something.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try to enabled template hints to be really sure that you are editing the right file

Comment: Doh! Don't know why I didn't bother with template hints. Turns out these fields are references via `..template/persistent/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml`. Didn't realize persist cart resulted in different template files being used here. Thank you, kind sir. Provide an answer & I'll accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to enabled template hints to be really sure that you are editing the right file